# Map a table of a cassandra database using spark and RDD

Tags: java, mapreduce, apache-spark, rdd

i have to map a table in which is written the history of utilization of an app. The table has got these tuples:

```
<AppId,date,cpuUsage,memoryUsage>
<AppId,date,cpuUsage,memoryUsage>
<AppId,date,cpuUsage,memoryUsage>
<AppId,date,cpuUsage,memoryUsage>
<AppId,date,cpuUsage,memoryUsage>
```

`AppId` is always different, because is referenced at many app, `date` is expressed in this format `dd/mm/yyyy hh/mm` `cpuUsage` and `memoryUsage` are expressed in `%` so for example:

```
<3ghffh3t482age20304,230720142245,0.2,3,5>
```

I retrieved the data from cassandra in this way (little snippet):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Cluster cluster;
        Session session;
        cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoint("127.0.0.1").build();
        session = cluster.connect();
        session.execute("CREATE KEYSPACE IF NOT EXISTS foo WITH replication "
                + "= {'class':'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor':3};");
        String createTableAppUsage = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS foo.appusage"
                + "(appid text,date text, cpuusage double, memoryusage double, "
                + "PRIMARY KEY(appid,date) " + "WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (time ASC);";
        session.execute(createTableAppUsage);
        // Use select to get the appusage's table rows
        ResultSet resultForAppUsage = session.execute("SELECT appid,cpuusage FROM foo.appusage");
       for (Row row: resultForAppUsage)
             System.out.println("appid :" + row.getString("appid") +" "+ "cpuusage"+row.getString("cpuusage"));
        // Clean up the connection by closing it
        cluster.close();
    }
```

***So, my problem now is to map the data by `key value` and create a tuple integrating this code (snippet that's doesn't work):***

```
        <AppId,cpuusage>

        JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> saveTupleKeyValue =someStructureFromTakeData.mapToPair(new PairFunction<String, String, Integer>() {
            public Tuple2<String, Integer> call(String x) {
                return new Tuple2(x, y);
            }
```

***how i can map appId and cpuusage using RDD and the reduce `eg. cpuusage >50`?***

Any help?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. You would like to replace ` session.execute("SELECT appid,cpuusage FROM foo.appusage");` by the equivalent spark - cassandra connection API expression?

Comment: @maasg hi, my problem is that, after retrieving the data from cassandra , as shown with the code above, i want to create a dataset RDD to map <AppId,cpuusage> and make operation on reduce on this.. eg. Reduce on utilization of the cpu >50.. and so. How i can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have a valid SparkContext `sparkContext` already created, have added the spark-cassandra connector dependencies  to your project and configured your spark application to talk to your cassandra cluster (see [docs](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/0_quick_start.md) for that), then we can load the data in an RDD like this:

```
val data = sparkContext.cassandraTable("foo", "appusage").select("appid", "cpuusage")
```

In Java, the idea is the same but it requires a bit more plumbing, described [here](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/7_java_api.md)

Comment: thanks for the answer, i configured everything.. i can perform queries, etc.. So it's possible to return a map, in this example `val data` is a rdd map?

Comment: @OiRc RDDs are collections and do not restrict that keys are duplicated, so they do not comply with the 'Map' (as in datastructure) contract. What functionality do you require from a Map? There's probably a way in Spark.

Comment: no no, i dont want to use java map.. with the term map i meant that i want to include all <key, value> pairs , and then reduce them. can u see this [question, related to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30758877/making-operations-before-returning-value-inisde-reducebykey) , can u give me an answer on this? What i want to know, if it's possible to do operation on `reduceByKey` function, before returning something.

Comment: Can you do this inisde of a rdd map? Like reading data from inside a rdd map?

Comment: @ArditMeti no, you can't use the `sparkContext` from within an RDD function closure